# Check if textbox has same value to other textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I want to check if there are similar value in my textboxes, I have 10 Textboxes, and on button click I want to validate if there are the same vales

```
for (int c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
{
    TextBox check_subjName = table_textboxes.FindControl("subject_name" + c.ToString()) as TextBox;

    for (int b = 1; b <= 10; b++)
    {
        TextBox check_subjName2 = table_textboxes.FindControl("subject_name" + b.ToString()) as TextBox;

        if (c != b)
        {
            if (check_subjName.Text == check_subjName2.Text)
            {
              //there are similar values
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, what are _similar values_? If you mean _equal_ don't say similar.

Answer (score 2):

So it is valid if all textboxes have different values. You could use LINQ:

```
List<string> textList = table_textboxes.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(txt => txt.ID.StartsWith("subject_name"))
    .Select(txt => txt.Text.Trim())
    .ToList();
var distinctTexts = new HashSet<string>(textList);
bool allDifferent = textList.Count == distinctTexts.Count;
```

here  a slightly optimized approach (in this case micro optimization):

```
var textList = table_textboxes.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(txt => txt.ID.StartsWith("subject_name"))
    .Select(txt => txt.Text.Trim());
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
bool allDifferent = textList.All(set.Add);
```

Comment: The things we do for science. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: i've added another one which i like most ;)